# Redux Wordpress Framework. array dump of redux options

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I have the latest Redux framework in the latest wordpress. If I make a copy of the redux sample options and trim it down to only one checkbox option it works.
If I then add a media selector field, and select or add an image using the media selector, wordpress crashes and dumps an array of the redux options.

Now, when I try and browse to the WP admin page, all I get is an array dump of redux options.

If I clear all cookies, and remove the redux options from the WP options table, I still get the array dump. Basically I cannot access the WP console at all.

Clearly redux is bombing out somehwere, but I dont know why, and I am not sure how to track it down.

Comment: It has something to do with the compile property of the media field. If I set compile to false for the field, the problem goes away. Now I need to learn more about how the compile flag works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler flag fires an action whenever a field denoted as compiler => true is changed. It's a way for you to integrate like a less/scss/ or just plain CSS compiling on save.

;)

Comment: Turns out I just did not read your theme options example carefully enough. (slap of forehead).